# How to create multipolygon shapely geometry in one row of geopandas dataframe?

Tags: geopandas, shapely, multipolygons

I have a multipolygon geometry which consists of a list of polygon geometries (3 in this example). I want to create a geodataframe and assign it to just one row. However, when I do the following it creates multiple rows.

Any help would be appreciated !

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import shape
>>> geo={'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': [[[[-6.89361451404645, 42.3483702456613], [-6.88669573921854, 42.3512517221675], [-6.87580712586245, 42.3552054810059], [-6.86866686394711, 42.3573490202175], [-6.86634649451855, 42.3578029961007], [-6.86485929944272, 42.3578451095022], [-6.86269565884165, 42.3567199999001], [-6.84977005165036, 42.3574553272632], [-6.85736376939718, 42.3584219957405], [-6.86260312778948, 42.3586101962362], [-6.86540904591301, 42.3592523372132], [-6.86769848173221, 42.3602680395218], [-6.86944163436685, 42.3613226434774], [-6.875639521488, 42.3661014013158], [-6.87837881937712, 42.3659090495874], [-6.88128451646765, 42.3660684347702], [-6.89613000001251, 42.3681444544187], [-6.90629355446821, 42.3611397165696], [-6.91134851142469, 42.3579245448312], [-6.91590536445934, 42.3556212772542], [-6.92234623065452, 42.352847993855], [-6.92358612842103, 42.3477036195428], [-6.9224104785545, 42.3439383624458], [-6.91770201332808, 42.3426902193944], [-6.90512650312747, 42.343936876722], [-6.9031378495764, 42.3439369775367], [-6.90191893841204, 42.3435986892315], [-6.89791212110307, 42.3461065492655], [-6.89361451404645, 42.3483702456613]]], [[[-6.89906785460217, 42.4682161832092], [-6.8985645069621, 42.470555820794], [-6.89858965513706, 42.4739212739318], [-6.89896550934163, 42.4765974195716], [-6.89972491760736, 42.4787657510451], [-6.9009810281459, 42.4802088026149], [-6.90230301564329, 42.4804035982091], [-6.90426571956671, 42.4800515116974], [-6.90827881089143, 42.4788005356882], [-6.91660939687048, 42.4756837812393], [-6.92382490186326, 42.474250220658], [-6.9265398868427, 42.4731320663596], [-6.927085378973, 42.4726705844922], [-6.92751384817931, 42.4720387429714], [-6.92793713400628, 42.4707715563402], [-6.92809711825426, 42.469121060489], [-6.92777864404758, 42.4655184358035], [-6.9265916168156, 42.460554962602], [-6.92509229324126, 42.4566502755129], [-6.92312921129026, 42.4529560798592], [-6.91994977756089, 42.4483393479285], [-6.91714736214994, 42.445084760463], [-6.91523950238876, 42.4432753489897], [-6.91432193977259, 42.4426295412105], [-6.91346078340642, 42.4422568680072], [-6.91227481057592, 42.4422099855322], [-6.91121575180791, 42.4427776558529], [-6.91058022044174, 42.4434975209533], [-6.91000109532557, 42.4444905206296], [-6.90674756055746, 42.4519678712067], [-6.90334259105767, 42.4586766049039], [-6.90013178996497, 42.4652742523013], [-6.89906785460217, 42.4682161832092]]], [[[-6.81153692785486, 42.38608709317], [-6.81255364283188, 42.389076878809], [-6.81428465162502, 42.3928882452291], [-6.81468909293668, 42.3942970262505], [-6.81502856739456, 42.3965697891244], [-6.8150767586934, 42.3981913586016], [-6.81488185813205, 42.4007833041592], [-6.81391983219631, 42.405510635491], [-6.81354770683345, 42.4084498797579], [-6.81360710668831, 42.4124126081536], [-6.81406833183345, 42.4154174564801], [-6.81488670719631, 42.4184504208322], [-6.81700648277012, 42.4245123095467], [-6.81829511926674, 42.4294140920437], [-6.81898116245038, 42.4332326515733], [-6.8198464186291, 42.4413041712813], [-6.82043986166016, 42.4449014594344], [-6.82104066966606, 42.4459522550983], [-6.82188536934636, 42.4467141034876], [-6.82339631054119, 42.4475679287968], [-6.82520716870599, 42.4482527587704], [-6.82670080610246, 42.4485898913254], [-6.8278429373007, 42.4485693985685], [-6.83292590445095, 42.4467192778025], [-6.84029070701108, 42.4443130224279], [-6.84419676594343, 42.4433610436994], [-6.84792497293665, 42.442772924522], [-6.85233512738876, 42.4425494530441], [-6.85882703332382, 42.4427959126746], [-6.86207019904241, 42.4431158543985], [-6.86826707567392, 42.4431984565626], [-6.86971582822253, 42.4429462314883], [-6.87071979951853, 42.4423075911722], [-6.87138234339051, 42.4415737757853], [-6.87343079514828, 42.4381019289848], [-6.87540506959181, 42.4356805263046], [-6.87730718261172, 42.4339309548587], [-6.87994811762039, 42.4321507482297], [-6.88482749307854, 42.4293696834051], [-6.89288504801627, 42.4252654154878], [-6.90380506518841, 42.4199717157414], [-6.91512371615772, 42.414746875], [-6.90892681128518, 42.4134221875], [-6.90518184926205, 42.4129543241767], [-6.89684841190103, 42.4114517049355], [-6.89382995952878, 42.4112506910577], [-6.89044820655216, 42.4118417747366], [-6.88899405368913, 42.4113504325048], [-6.88535290642418, 42.4093367301526], [-6.87968569673017, 42.4057680005089], [-6.87414202824488, 42.4020377762816], [-6.87059213937194, 42.3993812288458], [-6.86765946068107, 42.3968980089979], [-6.86534399217227, 42.3945881167378], [-6.86414324104532, 42.3931444816688], [-6.86243928318094, 42.3904912241775], [-6.86143446636381, 42.3892932385407], [-6.86020235510347, 42.3881839241729], [-6.85874294939991, 42.387163281074], [-6.85612766376356, 42.385798575055], [-6.85410002195198, 42.3849996101285], [-6.84390772477599, 42.3822068637876], [-6.83932508071557, 42.3805370409279], [-6.83745999207373, 42.3794742338664], [-6.83322271926195, 42.3756476996947], [-6.83216467694021, 42.3748753255289], [-6.82967109419671, 42.373518847268], [-6.82611729148701, 42.3719774181725], [-6.8235117854645, 42.3715185151684], [-6.82153020724814, 42.3716568375518], [-6.81952510157509, 42.3722087310524], [-6.81681502907838, 42.3735879219019], [-6.81433436043164, 42.3754585172813], [-6.81253514636759, 42.377414128838], [-6.81141738688623, 42.3794547565721], [-6.81098108198756, 42.3815804004834], [-6.811094251368, 42.3837911369289], [-6.81153692785486, 42.38608709317]]]]}
>>> geo_shape=shape(geo_shape)

>>> import geopandas as gpd
>>> df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id':1,'geometry':geo_shape})
>>> df
   id                                           geometry
0   1  POLYGON ((-6.89361 42.34837, -6.88670 42.35125...
1   1  POLYGON ((-6.89907 42.46822, -6.89856 42.47056...
2   1  POLYGON ((-6.81154 42.38609, -6.81255 42.38908...
```

Comment: I guess you meant `geo_shape = shape(geo)`. Thank you, anyway, that worked for me. Shapely nicely detects the type and coordinates and converts it into its own internal representation, regardless of whether type is actually `'Polygon'` or `'MultiPolygon'`.

Answer (score 3):

I just found the solution by doing the following. Hope it helps !

```
>>> df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id':[1],'geometry':[geo_shape]})
>>> df
   id                                           geometry
0   1  MULTIPOLYGON (((-6.89361 42.34837, -6.88670 42...
```